# IIS worker process continually increase memory usage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, memory-management, memory-leaks, perfview

We are running a web site on a machine with 16 GB RAM, IIS 8.5 and .Net 4.5.2.

After recycle our web site w3wp process memory increase to 9 GB in a day.

(Machine wide view but only our web site worker process memory usage increase)
[image: Machine wide view but only our web site worker process memory usage increase]

When I got a heap snapshot to worker process with PerfView I see that most of memory is hold by MemoryCache

[image: First view after snapshot]

When I go to MemoryCache detail I see 3 named cache.
One of them is default one and we do not put anything on it.
Other one called timeless, we put small amount of data which will live until recycle
And biggest one (named _cache), we put html outputs on it and it increases to 70K-80K item, around 10 to 30 min cache time.

[image: MemoryCache Detail]

When I right click _cache item and open Memory > View Object I see a list as follows:

[image: Cache item list]

I am taking a list of cache items and their sizes and try to sum of them and I see that total item size lower then 100 MB.

Is there any way that I can see what is increase continually ?

Comment: You may want to check the Perf Mon counters for Memory (both total system and .Net Memory) for your w3wp process.  It's possible that something in your memory cache is consuming un-managed memory as well.